# How to submit the form in HIPPO cms ?? I can't understand the document at the hippo.com regarding the forms as it's not much clear

Tags: forms, hippocms

I have created a form in hippo cms using free marker but unable to submit it at the desired action as it's not much clear at http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hst-2-forms.html. I am a newbee to hippo cms so cant understand much from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the ver 7.9 document for such information.

http://www.onehippo.org/7_9/trails/developer-trail/develop-advanced-features/introduction.html

The tutorial includes the whole solution for data persistence from page.